# Azure Angular Routing not respected in the browser

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-devops, redirect

### Problem Description

I have an Angular App I put together using the CLI, and deployed to azure semi successfully. Unfortunately, when I navigate to my site, routes are not respected within the browser. Basically, once you get to the site the route is static in the browser. But only when deployed to azure. Locally, everything works right.

### Simple walkthrough

For example:

Say we start with - http://my-awesome.site/

That route will load, it will function properly.

Then we click a link that takes us to http://my-awesome.site/route-here

That works, it takes me to that route. Except if I look at my browser window it still reads:

http://my-awesome.site/

Also, If I start on http://my-awesome.site/route-here the browser will reflect the proper route. Until you navigate to ANY OTHER ROUTE. Basically, the route you use to get to my site is static in the browser, I can do NOTHING to change it.

### What keeps me up at night

Locally, it all works correctly.

localhost:4200/ works, clicking localhost:4200/some-route works, the browser updates and reflects the new url of localhost:4200/some-route

### Useful information

I deployed to Azure through VSTS. I'm not exactly sure what's running udner the hood. Like honestly, I'm new to deploying Angular, and I really put the 'No' in "Node.js Experience". I was recently informed that my windows app server is running IIS pretending to be node, which pretty much blew my mind.

### Vain attempt to work the problem a different way

So, I stood up a Linux App Server and created a linux build server, and added a server folder, with an index.js and package.json with code from borrowed from John Papa's github

#### index.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4200;
const publicweb = process.env.PUBLICWEB || './dist';
app.use(express.static(publicweb));
console.log(`serving \\${publicweb}`);
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    tres.sendFile(`index.html`, { root: publicweb });
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on http://localhost:4200`));
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "one-with-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "express": "^4.15.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

and then I followed the tutorial found  at

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wael-kdouh/2017/09/11/deploying-your-angular-application-to-azure-using-visual-studio-team-services-vsts/

To successfully deploy my site.

### Except that was a pile of failure

When I deployed it to my original windows azure server, the routes were STILL NOT RESPECTED. With the added bonus that if you came in with a route to anywhere, you lost. You got a full-on 404. Because Reasons. Ok, frankly that's part of why I'm here.

### Also Linux was not my key to success

No, no it wasn't. I mentioned that Linux box earlier. And I totally tried to configure the VSTS build to deploy there. And it did deploy there "successfully". I can get 503s or 404s from that server but I don't get anything else.

### What I would like

Some direction.

Maybe I've missed a setting in a configuration file that would be like an application setting named "LetAngularRespectRoutesInTheBrowserWhenNotOnLocalhost"

or

Maybe I missed something in that simple index.js file

or

Maybe Linux actually is the key and I need to figure out what's wrong with that build.

### Lastly

Thank you

Comment: Try to download the build artifact to your local machine and run it to check whether it works? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, can you share the sample project on the OneDrive?

Comment: hrmmmm... if I build it, the dist folder that I'm publishing looks like this:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhwizZ0b-OWciEhL-S0Bi8gqrgvT

Comment: I can confirm that if I serve that up locally (running "http-server ./") it routes properly and reflects the routes in the browser properly.

Comment: Do you mean you download the published files (you shared) and run it locally, it works fine? How do you run this app?

Comment: I ran it using http-server. And yes, that was what I meant. But also, I was able to find the solution to the problem, and I'll see if I can't outline it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Solution

Yes, I was able to find the solution.

### What was wrong

#### Short Version: It was None of the things I thought was wrong

I sat down with some experts at a conference and together we got to the bottom of this mind bender.

#### More Detail

I registered my domain with GoDaddy.com. And then I set up a permanent forwarding to where I hosted the site in azure at (some-domain).azurewebsites.net.

Apparently, GoDaddy does something very interesting when you redirect this way. It returns an extremely simple page with an `<iframe></iframe>` that actually points at your redirected site. Which sounds ridiculous, but yeah. Like seriously, I wouldn't have believed it unless I saw the two get requests for the web page, one at (my-site).com/some-route and another asking for the same page at (my-azure-site).azurewebsites.net/some-route from.

That means that when I was navigating to different pages, Angular was working it's magic and attempting to update the routes just like it should. Except all of that goodness was sitting behind the window into my site that is the `<iframe>`. So the browser was never changing the page it was on. But everything looked correct.

### How we solved it

The solution was actually fairly simple.

#### Fix DNS entries

We just had to update a couple of DNS settings in GoDaddy.

- Ip Address

  - Type: A
  - Name: @
  - Value: (ip-address-from-azure)
- Azure Site Address

  - Type: TXT
  - Name: @
  - Value: (your-site).azurewebsites.net

Image of the settings: [GoDaddy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSGPf.png)

#### Update Azure

In the Azure Portal:

Navigate to the Custom Domains Settings : Home > (your-site-name) > Custom Domains (It's under settings)

Add your (owned-domain) to the list of custom hostnames. You may need to validate it, and that's why you have to do the DNS settings first (and give them a second to propagate).

Image of the settings: [Azure Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QuTm.png)

### Lastly

Thank you to those who helped and attempted to help.

Huge Shout out to Asim Hussain, and Sander Elias who were the experts who helped me figure this out at ngConf.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to but forgot that I hadn't yet. It wouldn't allow me to accept it for like at least a day or something.