# how to resolve the redirection problem into another page in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, redirect

so I am working on a website, and I would like to go from the home page to a registration page I am using the Angular framework, and the problem is I can't even use the href tag in the templates(HTML) for some reason it doesn't work here is the template code of the home page:

```
  <div class="col-lg-4 mt-2">
      <div class="stepBox">
        <h1>Nous Rejoindre</h1>
        <p>text</p>
<!--        <button class="info-button"  ></button>-->
       <a href="/register">Rejoindre</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried to follow many tutorial videos and website examples, but none of them works.
first, I have tried to specify more for the file location :

```
<a href="src/app/register">Rejoindre</a>
```

and then I tried the routerLink function that comes with angular
this is the app.modules.ts (code):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserService } from './users.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import {FooterComponent} from "./footer/footer.component";
import {RouterLink, RouterModule, RouterOutlet, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home/home.component";
import {RegisterComponent} from "./register/register.component";
import {AuthentificationComponent} from "./authentification/authentification.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path:'header',component: HeaderComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    AuthentificationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    FormsModule, HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

so why does even a simple href doesn't want to work?

Comment: Try using the routerLink attribute, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72408104/1882699.